# What is Azure Active Directory token request rate throttle limit?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created a Web API that uses AAD for authentication. The client is a daemon application requesting tokens from AAD using client id and secret.
I was doing a stress test on the client/web API where a client requests a token for each call to the service.

After around 26 mins of the test run, I start to see a very high request rate error from AAD when trying to get the token.

I understand I can reuse the token and avoid the issue but, I am curious to know what's the throttle limit? Does anyone have a pointer to the document explaining the request rate limit/throttle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Throttling behavior can be dependent on the type and number of requests. For example, if you have a very high volume of requests, all requests types are throttled. Threshold limits vary based on the request type. When you reach the limit, you receive the HTTP status code **429 Too many requests**. Exact request rate limit is not exposed currently.

Please refer these articles which may help you in understanding more.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#retry-usage-guidance